# How To Find Replication Queue is Blocked Programmatically

Tags: aem

On AEM CaaS, we are trying to send email notification If replication queue is stuck via custom ReplicationEventHandler. We used the agent manager to get the replication queue and trying to add send email logic when queue is blocked.

We have applied 2 approaches based upon the API Docs which doesn't seems working.

Approach 1 : This sends the emails multiple times, even queue is not blocked

```
     for (Agent agent : agentsMap.values()) {
            if (agent.isEnabled() && agent.getId().equals("publish")) {
                ReplicationQueue replicationQueue = agent.getQueue();
                    if(replicationQueue.getStatus().getNextRetryTime() != 0) {
                        Map<String, String> emailParams = new HashMap<>();
                        emailParams.put("agentId",agent.getId());
                        emailParams.put("agentName",agent.getConfiguration().getConfigPath());
                        sendEmail(emailParams);
                        log.info("::: Replication Queue Blocked :::");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Approach 2 : This doesn't trigger email, even queue is blocked.

```
if(agent.isValid() && agent.isEnabled()) {
            ReplicationQueue replicationQueue = agent.getQueue();
            if(!replicationQueue.entries().isEmpty()) {
                ReplicationQueue.Entry firstEntry = replicationQueue.entries().get(0);
                if(firstEntry.getNumProcessed() > 3) {
                    // Send Email That Queue Is Blocked
                }
            } else {
               // Queue is Not Empty
            }
        }
```

Looking for solution..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
import com.day.cq.replication .*;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
// getting agent manager object
@Reference
private AgentManager agentManager;

// list of publish instance ids - fill this list your agent ids
private static final List<String> publishAgentIds = Arrays.asList("publish_1", "publish_2");

// place for other code
// returns false if queue of at least one agent contains 500 or more items according to your requirement
// do a check under if (replicationQueueCheck()){ //your code for email}
private boolean replicationQueueCheck() {
    boolean result = true;
    for (Agent agent : getAgents()) {
        // checking if queue size is bigger than 500 if so, false will be returned, in other case, next agent will be verified
        if (agent.getQueue().entries().size() >= 500) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private List<Agent> getAgents() {
    List<Agent> agents = new ArrayList<Agent>();
    for (Agent agent : agentManager.getAgents().values()) {
        // filtering agents by ids, and selecting only publish related agents
        if (agent.isEnabled() && agent.isValid() && publishAgentIds.contains(agent.getId())) {
            agents.add(agent);
        }
    }
    return agents;
}
```